# How to prepend slice to 2D slice in Go?

Tags: go, slice

```
var twoDiamArr [][]int
var arr []int

// .... some code to add values to the above slices

// this works, and adds arr to the end of twoDiamArr:
twoDiamArr := append(twoDiamArr, arr)

// I expected this to add arr to the beginning of twoDiamArr, but it doesn't 
twoDiamArr := append(arr, twoDiamArr...)
```

How can I add `arr` to the beginning of `twoDiamArr` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `append()` function expects the *first* argument passed to it to be the value that will be returned and everything starting from the second argument will be appended to it.

So if you pass a two-dimensional array inside `append()` as a first argument, you will have a two-dimensional array returned from it.

The expression `append(arr, twoDiamArr...)` is the opposite, because you are trying to put elements of a two-dimensional array inside another one-dimensional. As a result you have one dimensional array with all elements from two-dimensional

Instead, you can use a two-dimensional slice literal with the value you want to have as the first element. Everything spread in the second argument will be appended after it.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var twoDimensional = [][]int{{1}, {2}}
    var oneDimensional = []int{3}

    twoDimensional = append([][]int{oneDimensional}, twoDimensional...)

    fmt.Println(twoDimensional)
    // prints [[3] [1] [2]]
}
```